# Get all values in an array between a specific range in a rangeslider. (jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-slider

I want to get all values, between a specific range set by the user with a jquery ui rangeSlider, in an array.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

```html
</script>


<div>

    <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />

<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

So in this example when i set the range from 75 to 90 and i push a submit button i want to get an array like so:

```
var myArray = ['75','76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90'] ;
```

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need this but here is a simple solution to your request :

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
  var start = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 );
  var end = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 );
  var myArray = range(start, end);
  // do your things here
  return false;
});

function range(start, end) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = start; i <= end; i++)
    arr.push(i);
  return arr;
}
```